# How to update react version in a package

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While running `npm ls react`, I get this:

```
PS > npm ls react
├─┬ @headlessui/react@1.7.15
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @heroicons/react@2.0.18
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @mux/mux-video-react@0.7.14
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @n8tb1t/use-scroll-position@2.0.3
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @portabletext/react@2.0.2
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @react-google-maps/api@2.18.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @sanity/block-content-to-react@3.0.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @shopify/cli-hydrogen@3.39.0
│ ├─┬ @shopify/cli-kit@3.39.0
│ │ ├─┬ ink@3.2.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ react-reconciler@0.26.2
│ │ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped invalid: "^17.0.2" from node_modules/ink/node_modules/react-reconciler
│ │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ └── react@17.0.2
│ └─┬ @shopify/hydrogen@0.26.0
│   └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @shopify/cli@3.44.1
│ ├─┬ @shopify/cli-kit@3.44.1
│ │ └── react@17.0.2
│ └─┬ @shopify/plugin-did-you-mean@3.44.1
│   └─┬ @shopify/cli-kit@3.44.1
│     └── react@17.0.2
├─┬ @shopify/hydrogen@1.6.6
│ ├─┬ @xstate/react@3.0.1
│ │ ├── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ │ └─┬ use-isomorphic-layout-effect@1.1.2
│ │   └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-error-boundary@3.1.4
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-helmet-async@1.3.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @tippyjs/react@4.2.6
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @types/react-datepicker@4.11.2
│ └─┬ react-popper@2.3.0
│   └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ embla-carousel-react@7.1.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-cookie@4.1.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-datepicker@4.15.0
│ ├─┬ react-onclickoutside@6.12.2
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-ga@3.3.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-hook-form@7.45.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-icons@4.10.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-instantsearch-hooks-web@6.45.1
│ ├─┬ react-instantsearch-hooks@6.45.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-map-gl@7.1.2
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-social-media-embed@2.3.5
│ ├─┬ react-sub-unsub@2.1.10
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-twitter-embed@4.0.4
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-youtube@10.1.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-type-animation@2.1.2
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├── react@18.2.0
└─┬ swr@2.2.0
  ├── react@18.2.0 deduped
  └─┬ use-sync-external-store@1.2.0
    └── react@18.2.0 deduped
```

I found that the `@shopify/cli-kit` package has `17.0.2` of react while all other packages are using `18.0.2`, can I update react of this package?

Answer (score 0):

As i remember, when multiple version of a package are defined in dependencies, only the highest version of that package will be installed and every other dependency packages gonna use that highest version. Or when an additional package have to use exactly listed version of dependency, it will be installed in their own node_modules folder of that package.

If you still want to edit the package to the version you like. U can try **patch-package** module to save your own dev version in your project

[patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).